# Material Components Doesn't Work properly

Tags: android, material-components

I'm trying to use material components beside AppCompact so i did following things

1- I created a style parent to AppCompact and called it AppTheme for my global theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/iranyekanwebregular</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

2- According to this (https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) article i made a TextInputEditText inside TextInputLayout with outLineBox style and that is what exactly the mentioned article said.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_hive_desc"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/tied_movement_desc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/add_apiary_desc"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

,but it does't work and when I'm trying to open the actiity it crashes and this the error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.soroushkh.mybees, PID: 22912
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.soroushkh.mybees/com.soroushkh.mybees.AddApiaryActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Binary XML file line #33: 
 Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #33: Error inflating class 
 com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.soroushkh.mybees.AddApiaryActivity.onCreate(AddApiaryActivity.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at 
    android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
    E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component 
    requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:217)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:145)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:115)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:451)
    at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:410)
```

and it's asking me for Theme.MaterialComponents and when i implement it , it ruins all my custom designs.
what should i do please answer.

Comment: You **have to use** a [Material Components theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#4-change-your-app-theme-to-inherit-from-a-material-components-theme)

Comment: i know but in material.io the article says that you can use AppCompact as global theme and use the  outLineBox as style without problem . but in action it doesn't work

Comment: Have you used  android:name property in your xml file?

Comment: no i didn't . you mean like when we want to use mapView?! interesting! what should i write inside the property to get a TextInputLayout with out line box?

Comment: you can use `setTheme(R.style.textTheme)` for custom designs

Answer (score 1):

Change your style's parent to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.*` and see if it works?

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        .
</style>
```

Comment: i'd tried this before the activity will open and the textInputLayout will work too but it will change everything else that i'd built .

Comment: what do you mean every thing else?. if you mean style of other components. 
you should change them also, it is because of some defaults on material theme has been changed.

Comment: there are other styles may help , like `parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light`,`Light.DarkActionBar` , `Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: as i mentioned in the question this article [https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) says you can use AppCompact as global theme and MaterialComponents as style for each element  . but in action it doesn't work

Comment: if you see android source code, material them is child of appCompat theme. `<style name="Platform.MaterialComponents.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>` 
but just added a lot of new styles.
also in article says ," However, you must add the following new theme attributes to your existing app theme, or you will encounter ThemeEnforcement errors. "

therefore if you whant use appcompat.theme you should add them all.

Comment: if you define material components globally or on an activity and defining styles separately for each button or anything else has no effect . material components will change everything that is not material design.

Comment: i think if you use name of an existing style it won't make the attributes of that style child of another style , it just overrides it with no super attributes .

Answer (score 0):

As you [mentioned](http://Doing%20an%20app-wide%20migration%20by%20changing%20your%20app%20theme%20to%20inherit%20from%20a%20Material%20Components%20theme%20is%20the%20recommended%20approach.%20However,%20be%20sure%20to%20test%20thoroughly%20afterwards,%20as%20components%20in%20existing%20layouts%20may%20change%20their%20looks%20and%20behavior.)

> Doing an app-wide migration by changing your app theme to inherit from
>   a Material Components theme is the recommended approach. However, be
>   sure to test thoroughly afterwards, as components in existing layouts
>   may change their looks and behavior.

I tried same code and it's crashing

After changing

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

To

```
Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar
```

it's working and if you want to set custom style then you can add           `activity!!.setTheme(R.style.textTheme)` in fragment/activity and apply theme

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: sorry but i didn't mentioned this :) . according to material.io documentations we can use widget.MaterialComponents...outLineBox with AppCompat app-wide integrated . but in action it doesn't work

Comment: Yes I know outline box integrated with Material components.but other than that if you want to use your custom design then you can use setTheme.

Comment: i tried this before . you can use android:theme property in manifest . there's no difference . if you want to understand what i'm talking about make a new project , add a TextInputEditText inside a TextInputLayout and set                 style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
for TextInputLayout and set the app theme Theme.AppCompact . MainActivity will crash.

Comment: @AliRasouli I will try this. Which custom design you want apply share your code here.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change your theme to inherit from a Material Components theme, you can inherit from a Material Components Bridge theme.

Bridge themes inherit from AppCompat themes, but also define the new Material Components theme attributes for you. If you use a bridge theme, you can start using Material Design components without changing your app theme.

You can read [here](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started#appcompat-themes).